# Style Sheets for Multiple QWidgets in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

How to create a Stylesheet for Mulitiple QLabels or Multiple Qwidgets in PyQt5 ?

For example, In my programme, I use 8 QLabels, Out of Which 4 QLabels belong to one family/group and another 4 have a another family/group. Now I want to create a separate style sheet for both families. First family (all 4 QLabels) have to set  the same property ( Background color, foreground color, Alignment, and font)  and the second family also have to set different properties.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget,QApplication,QLabel,QFormLayout

class Stylesheet_001(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Style Sheet Example_001")
        self.setMinimumSize(600,800)
        self.setMaximumSize(600,800)
        self.mydesign()

    def mydesign(self):
        lbl_normal   = QLabel("Total Available Items :")
        lbl_starts   = QLabel("Item Starts With :")
        lbl_contains = QLabel("Items Contains Anywhere :")
        lbl_end      = QLabel("Items Ends With :")

        lbl_normal_count   = QLabel("500")
        lbl_starts_count   = QLabel('50,000')
        lbl_contains_count = QLabel('5')
        lbl_ends_count     = QLabel('0')

        mylayout = QFormLayout()
        mylayout.addRow(lbl_normal  ,lbl_normal_count)
        mylayout.addRow(lbl_starts  ,lbl_starts_count)
        mylayout.addRow(lbl_contains,lbl_contains_count)
        mylayout.addRow(lbl_end     ,lbl_ends_count)

        self.setLayout(mylayout)

def main():
    myapp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mywindow = Stylesheet_001()
    mywindow.show()
    sys.exit(myapp.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

1) lbl_normal, 2) lbl_strats, 3) lbl_contains , 4) lbl_ends belong to one group (First) and another 4 Labels belong to  another group (second group).

**First group** have to set same, fore-ground color:Red,font : Caliber,10,Bold and Alignment to Right.
**Second group** have to set same, fore-ground colour:Green,font:system default and Alignment to Left.

Comment: Your question is unclear, can you try to better explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: @musicamante , as per your guide, now I elaborate my requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it :

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import  *

class Stylesheet_001(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Style Sheet Example_001")
        self.setMinimumSize(600,800)
       # self.setMaximumSize(600,800)
        self.mydesign()

    def mydesign(self):

        lbl_normal   = QLabel("Total Available Items :")
        lbl_starts   = QLabel("Item Starts With :")
        lbl_contains = QLabel("Items Contains Anywhere :")
        lbl_end      = QLabel("Items Ends With :")

        lbl_normal.setStyleSheet(self.stylesheet_family_1())
        lbl_starts.setStyleSheet(self.stylesheet_family_1())
        lbl_contains.setStyleSheet(self.stylesheet_family_1())
        lbl_end.setStyleSheet(self.stylesheet_family_1())

        lbl_normal_count   = QLabel("500")
        lbl_starts_count   = QLabel('50,000')
        lbl_contains_count = QLabel('5')
        lbl_ends_count     = QLabel('0')

        lbl_normal_count.setStyleSheet(self.stylesheet_family_2())
        lbl_starts_count.setStyleSheet(self.stylesheet_family_2())
        lbl_contains_count.setStyleSheet(self.stylesheet_family_2())
        lbl_ends_count.setStyleSheet(self.stylesheet_family_2())

        self.mylayout = QFormLayout()
        self.mylayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.mylayout.addRow(lbl_normal  ,lbl_normal_count)
        self.mylayout.addRow(lbl_starts  ,lbl_starts_count)
        self.mylayout.addRow(lbl_contains,lbl_contains_count)
        self.mylayout.addRow(lbl_end     ,lbl_ends_count)

        self.myframe    = QFrame()
        self.mainlayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.myframe.setFixedSize(400,300)
        self.myframe.setLayout(self.mylayout)

        self.mainlayout.addWidget(self.myframe)
        self.mainlayout.addStretch()
        self.setLayout(self.mainlayout)

    def stylesheet_family_1(self):
        return"""
        QLabel{
        background-color:'red';
        font-family: Caliber;
        font-style: normal;
        font-size:10pt;
        font-weight:normal;
        border-width:1px;
        border-color:black;
        border-top-color:black;
        border-style:outset;
        color:white;
        padding:6px;
        min-width:220px;
        qproperty-alignment:'AlignRight';   
        }
        """
    def stylesheet_family_2(self):
        return"""
        QLabel{
        background-color:'green';
        font-family: Caliber;
        font-style: normal;
        font-size:10pt;
        font-weight:bold;
        border-width:1px;
        border-color:black;
        border-top-color:black;
        border-style:outset;
        color:white;
        padding:1px;
        min-width:20px;
        qproperty-alignment:'AlignCenter|AlignRight';   
        }
        """


def main():
    myapp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mywindow = Stylesheet_001()
    mywindow.show()
    sys.exit(myapp.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: @bala For More Qt - CSS properties, follow this  :  **[link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html#css-properties)**

Comment: Answer by @kumar is more suitable for me

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QFormLayout,\
    QFrame, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Stylesheet_001(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Style Sheet Example_001")
        self.setMinimumSize(600,800)
        self.setMaximumSize(600,800)
        self.mydesign()

    def mydesign(self):

        # Red, same font : Caliber, 10, Bold, and Alignment to Right 
        lbl_normal   = QLabel("Total Available Items :", alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        lbl_normal.setMinimumWidth(180)
        lbl_starts   = QLabel("Item Starts With :", minimumWidth=180, alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        lbl_contains = QLabel("Items Contains Anywhere :", minimumWidth=180, alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        lbl_end      = QLabel("Items Ends With :", minimumWidth=180, alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        lbl_normal_count   = QLabel("500")
        lbl_starts_count   = QLabel('50,000')
        lbl_contains_count = QLabel('5')
        lbl_ends_count     = QLabel('0')

        mylayout = QFormLayout(self) 
        mylayout.addRow(lbl_normal  , lbl_normal_count)
        mylayout.addRow(lbl_starts  , lbl_starts_count)
        mylayout.addRow(lbl_contains, lbl_contains_count)
        mylayout.addRow(lbl_end     , lbl_ends_count)


QSS = """
QWidget > QLabel[text="Total Available Items :"],
QWidget > QLabel[text="Item Starts With :"],
QWidget > QLabel[text="Items Contains Anywhere :"],
QWidget > QLabel[text="Items Ends With :"] {
    background-color: red; 
    color: white;
    font: bold 10pt \"Caliber\";
}
QWidget > QLabel {
    background-color: green; 
    color: yellow;
    font: 10pt \"Caliber\";
}
"""

def main():
    myapp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp.setStyle('Fusion')
    myapp.setStyleSheet(QSS)
    mywindow = Stylesheet_001()
    mywindow.show()
    sys.exit(myapp.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]